# How does Oracle store integers?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, aws-sct

I have been tasked to convert some Oracle DB's to Postgresql, using AWS Schema Conversion Tool. Oracle only has the Number[(precision[,scale])] type. It would seem that Oracle stores integers using fixed-point. A lot of ID columns are defined as `Number(19,0)` which is being converted to `Numeric(19,0)` by SCT.

I've even seen one (so far) simple `Number` which is converted to `Double Precision`.

Postgres has proper scalar integer types like `bigint`.

On first blush it seems that storing integers as fixed-point numbers would be grossly inefficient in both storage and time compared to simple integers.

Am I missing something, does Oracle store them as efficient scalar ints under-the-covers?

Out of interest what's the best type for a simple ID column in Oracle?

Comment: "Oracle only has the Number[(precision[,scale])] type." is not accurate. [Oracle data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Data-Types.html#GUID-219C338B-FE60-422A-B196-2F0A01CAD9A4) also shows `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE`.

Comment: @MT0 I don't think it's a duplicate because this question is also asking about how to map that to a data type in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, the title states "How does Oracle store integers?" and the question asked is "does Oracle store them as efficient scalar ints under-the-covers?". The OP only mentions conversion to PostgreSQL as an (irrelevant) introduction to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's number data type is a variable length data type, which means that the value `1` uses less storage (and memory) than `123456789`

In theory `number(19,0)` should be mapped to `bigint`, however Oracle's `number(19,0)` allows storing a value like `9999999999999999999` which would exceed the range for a `bigint` in Postgres.

The bigget value a `bigint` can store is `9223372036854775807` - if that is enough for you, then stick with `bigint`.

If you really need higher values, you will have to bite the bullet and use `numeric` in Postgres.

Comment: In hindsight I'm not really sure what I was wanting to know as the Oracle DB is no longer relevant to this project and I don't want to learn more than I have to. I will have to check, but I seriously doubt the DB would overflow a `bigint` for an ID.